# External JS not Loaded in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a vue.js app and I require some external JS to work on all pages. I currently use [vue-script2](https://github.com/taoeffect/vue-script2) library to load these external JS into a component. The problem is that once the route changes the scripts are not loaded anymore. My guess is that once an instance of these scripts is created, they will not be recreated on route change. what should I do? P.S. importing the js files is not an option. they need to be directly mounted on component.
The following code is located in App.vue also tried putting it in each component and tried putting script tags directly in index.html. neither worked

```
 <script2 type="text/javascript">var plugin_path = '/static/assets/plugins/';</script2>
<script2 type="text/javascript" src="/static/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script2>
<script2 type="text/javascript" src="/static/assets/js/scripts.js"></script2>
<script2 type="text/javascript"
         src="/static/assets/plugins/slider.revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script2>
<script2 type="text/javascript"
         src="/static/assets/plugins/slider.revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script2>
<script2 type="text/javascript" src="/static/assets/js/view/demo.revolution_slider.js"></script2>
<script2 type="text/javascript" src="/static/assets/js/view/demo.shop.js"></script2>
```

**edit:** also tried putting scripts into webpack as a plugin and tried using [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader) with no luck

Comment: may you please mention your code or error you give?

Comment: @fatemefazli code added